# Setting a boolean in swiftui with if statement

Tags: swiftui

I'm very new to swiftui so I don't know if I'm doing completely wrong but the error is not helpful. Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct IntroScreenP2: View {
 var hasName: Bool = false
 @State private var firstName: String = ""
 @State private var lastName: String = ""
 var body: some View {
  VStack {
   if firstName != "" && lastName != "" {
    hasName = true
   }
   TextField("First Name", text: $firstName)
    .padding(.leading)
    .padding(.bottom, 5)
   Divider()
   TextField("Last Name", text: $lastName)
    .padding(.leading)
    .padding(.top, 5)
   }
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to set a boolean equal to true when the user enters their name in the text field. It keeps giving me an error saying "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Answer (score 1):

you cannot just "code" as usual in SwiftUI. SwiftUI requires that you return Views. 
Maybe you should read some Introduction and Tutorials to SwiftUI.

Here is the code "corrected". If you tell me what you want with your variable i can help you further more.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var hasName: Bool = false
    @State private var firstName: String = ""
    @State private var lastName: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if firstName != "" && lastName != "" {
              Text("Has name")
            }
            TextField("First Name", text: $firstName)
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
            Divider()
            TextField("Last Name", text: $lastName)
                .padding(.leading)
                .padding(.top, 5)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be incorrect to define `hasName` with `@State`. `@State` introduces a new source of truth, whereas here it should be a derived value, computed from `firstName` and `lastName`. This could be done by either making it a computed property, or by using `didSet` observers on `firstName` and `lastName` to update it after every change.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `set` it at all! Just make it computed:

```
var hasName: Bool { firstName != "" && lastName != "" }
```

---

**Note that** it's better to use `.isEmpty` instead:

```
var hasName: Bool { !firstName.isEmpty && !lastName.isEmpty }
```